# AppleScript tell Finder move -10000 Error "Handler can’t handle objects of this class"

Tags: applescript, finder

I've created directory structure and placed the `a` file in `A` directory:

```
~/A
~/B
```

In AppleScript I'm **trying to move file `a` from `A` to `B`**. Here is my code:

```
on run

    tell application "Finder"
        move POSIX file "~/A/a" to POSIX file "~/B"
    end tell

end run
```

But when I run the script I get error:

```
error "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class." number -10000
```

This is simplified version of my problem. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Any explaination why I get -1 for that question?

Comment: If I use /Users/username/A|B i get -10010

Comment: Explanation — dstPath: The new path for the item in srcPath. This path **must include the name of the file** or directory in its new location. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1413529-moveitematpath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
set myFile to POSIX file (POSIX path of (path to home folder) & "A/a.txt")
set myFolder to POSIX file (POSIX path of (path to home folder) & "B")
tell application "Finder" to move myFile to myFolder
```

Or:

```
set myFile to (path to home folder as text) & "A:a.txt"
set myFolder to (path to home folder as text) & "B"
tell application "Finder" to move myFile to myFolder
```

Comment: Does it work for you @adayzdone ? I tried to relaunch the Finder and restart OS X just in case if it is something wrong in my runtime or something... Didnt help

Comment: Are you sure the file is named a and not a.txt? Drag the file on an open script in AppleScript Editor to get its full path.

Comment: It's hard to admit, but yes... You're right with the file extension @adayzdone - edit your post and I'll accept your answer. The error message was missleading for me and actually I've checked if there is a difference between `POSIX file ... "A/a"` and `POSIX file ... "A/a.txt"` and they both are of furl class, so the error message doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Asbjørn Ulsberg, That was a rather superfluous edit, especially in light of the fact that replacing the existing _tab indention_ for the _code_ with  "```applescript" obviously does not apply  _syntax highlighting_ for **AppleScript** _code_! The only thing that may have needed improving was changing "-- OR" to "Or:". Hence a superfluous edit. Have a look at: [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: I did the edit for changing `--OR` to `Or:` and thought adding the fenced language specifiers was worth a shot. 